# Prove that the map of Insula can be coloured with three colours

Tags: graph-theory

> All countries in *Insula* border the sea and are connected. Prove that the map of Insula can be coloured with three colours such that bordering countries don't have the same colours. You are not allowed to use the four-colour theorem.

Now I'm confused by this. Assume we have $n-1$ countries connected with each other, and the $n$th country is connected to all of them. All countries border the sea. Say we use an induction argument; then we would have that for the case $n-1$ the countries can be coloured with three colours. However, if we add this $n$th country, then is it impossible to still have three colours, because we would simply need a new colour for the $n$th county?

This is the visualition of the problem:
[image]

**EDIT**

I think I'm getting the idea. Consider $n$ countries as in the hypothesis. Assume that for each $i\in\{2,\dots,n-1\}$ it holds that only $v_{i-1}$ and $v_{i+1}$ are neighbours, and for $v_1$ the only neighbour is $v_2$. This case can be coloured with two colours. If we consider an all-overlapping $n$th country, then we just add the third (free) colour. Now assume some country $i$ does border some other country $j$ than the just mentioned. This way it automatically "shields" its neighbours $v_{i+1},\dots,v_{j-1}$ (assuming without loss of generality that $i<j$). See picture;
[image]

Then the shielded countries don't really 'count' anymore in the alternating colouring we worked with in the beginning. So 'shielded' countries get lost, which leaves us with the possibility to colour them with the last remaining 'third' colour. It's not a rigorous proof, but this is my idea so far.

Answer (score 0):

This just shows that the induction won't work as you stated it. In this case, because your big $n$th country shields the $n+1$th from needing more colours.

A hint which I *think* leads to a solution: use strong induction instead, cutting through an existing country if necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by $n+1$th country? You mean $n-1$? Because there is no $n+1$ country.

Comment: I claim that you only needed $2$ colours for all the countries which are touching country $n$. If you try to induct past $n$, you will find yourself with spare colours; this general reason is why I claimed the above.

Comment: I'm slowly getting the idea! See my original post for the edit (I couldn't write it here, because I had to include a picture)